# Why the improper integral $\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x(\log x)^{n}}$ converges iff $ - n + 1 < 0$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was trying to answer this problem in preparation for GRE exam:

> [image]

And the answer was given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand why the improper integral converges iff $ - n + 1 < 0,$ could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: Log x diverges for $x\to \infty$, so you need to control that. In the specified range, Log x is raised to a negative power, thus it can be written as $\frac{1}{\log(x)^{n-1} }$ which tends to zero

Comment: change the limits of integration when you make your substitution; then it's literally just power rule (or log rule if $n=1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $-\frac{1}{n+1}(\log x)^{-n+1}$ we're essentially dealing with a power of $\log(x)$ (the term before it is a constant), which is (as said) a function that increases without bound as $x \to \infty$. Recall that $f(x)^{-a} = \frac{1}{f(x)^a}$ for all $a>0$. So the only way a power of log can tend to $0$ (as it should for convergence) is that the exponent is *negative* so that it appears in the denominator of a fraction, and in general $\frac{1}{y} \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$.

So we need $-n+1 < 0$ which is equivalent to $n>1$.

Comment: I think also in the solution if $n = -1$ is a typo and it should be $n = 1.$ .... am I correct?

Comment: @Smart20 yes, $\frac{1}{u^n} = \frac{1}{u}$ for $n=1$ and so has primitive $\log(u)$ as the special case.

Answer (score 1):

By the change of variable $x=e^u \implies dx=xdu$ the integral becomes

$$\int_e^\infty \frac1{x(\log x)^n}dx =\int_1^\infty\frac{du}{u^n}$$

which by direct calculation converges if and only if $n>1$.